# Counting the number of subsets of size $k$ of a multiset.

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

I have a multiset $G$ containing $n$ elements and I want to count the number of subsets that has $k$ elements and the ordering within the subsets does not matter. The multiset $G$ would look as this: $\{n_0 * 0, n_1 * 1, \dots, n_r * r\}$. Where $n_i$ is the number of occurrences of element $i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^r n_i = n$.

For example, take the multiset $S = \{0,0,1,2\}$ and $k=1$. The '$|$' denotes the separation of the elements that we choose and didn't choose. The large bracket '$\large\{$' encloses the multiset permutations that reduce to the same subset of cardinality $k=1$.
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\{0|0,1,2\}\\
\{0|0,2,1\}\\
\{0|1,0,2\}\\
\{0|1,2,0\}\\
\{0|2,0,1\}\\
\{0|2,1,0\}\\
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\{1|0,0,2\}\\
\{1|0,2,0\}\\
\{1|2,0,0\}
\end{cases}\\
\begin{cases}
\{2|0,0,1\}\\
\{2|0,1,0\}\\
\{2|1,0,0\}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

What would a formula to count the number of subsets of cardinality $k$ given an arbitrary $n,k$ and $n_i$'s.

Comment: [Here's a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06142.pdf) I found which derives a formula for future people that stumble onto this post.